# How to prevent Scala's pretty printer from removing CDATA?

Tags: xml, scala, pretty-print

I've used Scala xml PrettyPrinter library to format xml files. It removes the tags content that has CDATA section. How can I prevent PrettyPrinter from removing CDATA?

This is the code :

```
val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
printer.format(XML.loadString(input))
```

It converts `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[something]]></textFieldExpression>` to `<textFieldExpression>something</textFieldExpression>`

Comment: According to the XML spec those are equivalent, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's the PrettyPrinter that removes the CDATA, but the XML.loadString(...). If you try to create an XML like this and print it:

```
val input = <textFieldExpression>{new xml.PCData("something")}</textFieldExpression>
val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
printer.format(XML.loadString(input.toString))
// => <textFieldExpression>something</textFieldExpression>
printer.format(input)
// => <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[something]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: `XML.load(new java.io.StringReader("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><X><![CDATA[<b>Hello</b>]]></X>"""))` works for me and produces `scala.xml.Elem = <X>&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;</X>`